# Подскажите структуру данных

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Для написания программы мне понадобилась структура данных, обладающая определёнными свойствами.
Она должна хранить набор однотипных элементов.
Должна уметь добавлять и удалять элементы.
Элемент должен представлять собой набор (массив) двух целых чисел (координаты точки).
Я только начал изучать java. Поэтому я знаю пока только две списковых структуры - массив и ArrayList.
Массив мне не подходит, т.к. размер должен меняться в ходе программы.
Подскажите, подойдёт ли для моих целей ArrayList или какая-то другая структура данных.
Ещё раз требования:

1) хранить список элементов

2) добавлять элементы

3) удалять элементы

4) упорядочивать элементы НЕ нужно, мне не важно в каком порядке расположены элементы

5) элемент должен хранить 2 целых числа (пока не знаю в каком виде)

Подскажите на какую структуру данных обратить внимание?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList подойдёт, если создать некий класс, объект которого будет хранить оба числа. Пусть есть класс

```
class NumbersContainer(){
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    public NumbersContainer(int first, int second){
        this.firstNumber = first;
        this.secondNumber = second;
    }
}
```

Тогда создадим объект ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<NumbersContainer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

И будем добавлять экземпляра класса в `list`:

```
NumbersContainer firstSet = new NumbersContainer(1, 2);
list.add(firstSet);
```

Есть другой вариант решения: создадим Map и будем добавлять числа как пара ключ-значение. Эту схему лучше применять при каком-либо ведущем числе.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(1, 2);
```

При использовании Map важно помнить, что не может быть двух одинаковых ключей (первого числа в нашем случае)!